# Optimize text search

Tags: node.js, sql-server, search

I have an application which uses nodejs and `mssql` and used to store flat html content. I have used search utility here:

```
select * from MyTable where content like %search%
```

But it is taking almost 5 minute where I have 300 records.

Comment: What is the datadype of the "content" column and how big is the HTML content in that row?

Comment: If you're storing HTML, and you're enforcement of the tags is strict you might be able to use the `xml` data type and the indexing properties available there. You'll probably have luck with a full text index though.